Rebus RebusApplicationException 'Could not 'GetOrAdd' item with key 'outgoing-messages' as type
Error: InvalidOperationException: Cannot add OnCommit action on a completed transaction context.
Rebus.Exceptions.RebusApplicationException: 'Could not 'GetOrAdd' item with key 'outgoing-messages' as type System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1[Rebus.Transport.OutgoingTransportMessage]'
We are getting the above error when running the following piece of code.
`await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
     if (messageType == MessageType.Direct)
         // This line is the one thats called and errors
         await _messageBus.Send(message);
     else
         await _messageBus.Publish(message);
});`

A bit of context:
We use Rabbit MQ to communicate between our different microservices.
We host our applications in both Azure and AKS
We have an NVC project which fires off a direct message to our Mail Microservice to send out emails. (This works perfectly)
After each mail is sent we audit the result but putting an direct audit message on the message queue.(This is where the problem is and causes the error seen above.)
MVC configuration (The application that puts the direct email message on the queue)
 var messageQueuesConfig = configuration.GetRequiredSection("MessageQueues"); var transport = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<MessageBusTransportType>("Transport"); var hostName = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<string>("HostName"); var userName = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<string>("UserName"); var password = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<string>("Password"); var queuePrefix = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<string>("QueuePrefix"); var connectionString = MessageBusConnectionStringFactory.GetConnectionString(transport,   hostName, userName, password); services.AddRebus((config, provider) => config .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq(connectionString,  MessageBusQueueNameFactory.GetQueueName(MessageBusQueueIdentifier.Web, queuePrefix,    MessageBusQueueType.PubSub))) .Options(o => o.RetryStrategy(secondLevelRetriesEnabled: true)) .Routing(r => r.TypeBased() .Map<AuditEvent> (MessageBusQueueNameFactory.GetQueueName(MessageBusQueueIdentifier.Audit, queuePrefix,  MessageBusQueueType.Direct)) .Map<MailMessage>  (MessageBusQueueNameFactory.GetQueueName(MessageBusQueueIdentifier.Mail, queuePrefix,   MessageBusQueueType.Direct)) ), onCreated: async bus => { await bus.Subscribe<Event>(); } );
Mail Microservice configuration (The hosted service that picks up the direct email message from the queue)
`var messageQueuesConfig = configuration.GetRequiredSection("MessageQueues");
var transport = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<MessageBusTransportType>("Transport");
var hostName = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<string>("HostName");
var userName = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<string>("UserName");
var password = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<string>("Password");
var queuePrefix = messageQueuesConfig.GetValue<string>("QueuePrefix");
var connectionString = MessageBusConnectionStringFactory.GetConnectionString(transport,     
    hostName, userName, password);
    services.AddRebus((config, provider) => config
        .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq(connectionString,  
        MessageBusQueueNameFactory.GetQueueName(MessageBusQueueIdentifier.Mail, queuePrefix,  
        MessageBusQueueType.Direct)))
        .Options(o => o.RetryStrategy(secondLevelRetriesEnabled: true))
        .Routing(r => r.TypeBased()
            .Map<AuditEvent>
        (MessageBusQueueNameFactory.GetQueueName(MessageBusQueueIdentifier.Audit, queuePrefix, 
        MessageBusQueueType.Direct))
        ),
        onCreated: async bus =>
        {
            await bus.Subscribe<Event>();
        }
    );`

Here is the code that gets the direct message from the queue and processes the mail. Finally a new direct message is put on the queue to the Audit Microservice
`private readonly IBus _bus;
private readonly IMailClientFactory _mailClientFactory;
private readonly IAuditor _auditor;
private readonly ILogger<MailMessageHandler> _logger;
private readonly NotificationOptions _notificationOptions;
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
public MailMessageHandler(
    IBus bus,
    IMailClientFactory mailClientFactory,
    IAuditor auditor,
    ILogger<MailMessageHandler> logger,
    IOptionsSnapshot<NotificationOptions> notificationOptions
)
{
    _bus = bus;
    _mailClientFactory = mailClientFactory;
    _auditor = auditor;
    _logger = logger;

    if (notificationOptions == null) throw new    
     ArgumentNullException(nameof(notificationOptions));
    _notificationOptions = notificationOptions.Value;

    _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
}

public async Task Handle(MailMessage message)
{
   // Validation and setup for processing the mail
    try
    {
        _semaphore.Wait();
        await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            var result = await mailClient.SendEmailAsync(message);
            if (result.Errors.Any())
            {
                // Log errors
            }
            else
            {
                _ = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var auditEvent = new AuditEvent
                    {
                        AuditEventCode = AuditEventCode.EmailSent,
                        EventData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
                        {
                            // Our data
                        })
                    };
        After calling this line we get the issue.
                    _auditor.AuditEvent(auditEvent);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    // Does stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}`

The _audit class is declared as a singleton in the Mail Microservice start up code

When the line _auditor.AuditEvent(auditEvent); Is called the following code is executed.

`public void AuditEvent(AuditEvent auditEvent)
{
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(auditEvent);
if (auditEvent.AuditEventCode == AuditEventCode.NotSet)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("AuditEventCode must be set before calling this  
    method.");
_messageBus.SendDirectMessage(auditEvent);
}`

It's a puzzler as we can't solve the problem.
Can you someone help or point us in the right direction?
if we use a queue of type pub sub, it works
However we need both queues of type direct and pub sub

This is caused due to transaction context issues with Rebus and RabbitMQ. Avoid using Task.Run inside message handlers to ensure all processing happens within the transaction context. Refactor your code to make AuditEvent async and await it directly. Ensure Rebus is configured with proper transaction handling and retry strategies. Enable logging for further insights.
